# Could not find bot account token key, viber bot, node.js

Tags: node.js, viber-bot

I am kinda new to node.js and stackoverflow, but I am having some troubles with creating a viber bot. Using this https://chatbotslife.com/build-viber-bot-with-nodejs-a21487e5b65, created viber API but cannot find where do I place my API inside code.

```
const ViberBot = require('viber-bot').Bot,
  BotEvents = require('viber-bot').Events,
  TextMessage = require('viber-bot').Message.Text,
  express = require('express');
const app = express();

if (!process.env.BOT_ACCOUNT_TOKEN) {
  console.log('Could not find bot account token key.');
  return;
}
if (!process.env.EXPOSE_URL) {
  console.log('Could not find exposing url');
  return;
}

const bot = new ViberBot({
  authToken: process.env.BOT_ACCOUNT_TOKEN,
  name: "Quest Bot",
  avatar: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/BirthdayQuest.jpg"
});
bot.on(BotEvents.SUBSCRIBED, response => {
  response.send(new TextMessage(`Hi there ${response.userProfile.name}. I am ${bot.name}! Feel free to ask me anything.`));
});
bot.on(BotEvents.MESSAGE_RECEIVED, (message, response) => {
  response.send(new TextMessage(`Message received.`));
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use("/viber/webhook", bot.middleware());
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Application running on port: ${port}`);
  bot.setWebhook(`${process.env.EXPOSE_URL}/viber/webhook`).catch(error => {
    console.log('Can not set webhook on following server. Is it running?');
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to put the token in the `BOT_ACCOUNT_TOKEN` environment variable.

Comment: const bot = new ViberBot({
  authToken: process.env.BOT_ACCOUNT_TOKEN = //my token number,
it was not working still if you meant that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a variable first with single quotes 'including your API key here'

```
const bot_account = 'API KEY'
```

And then initialize your bot

```
 const bot = new ViberBot({
      authToken: bot_account,
      name: "Quest Bot",
      avatar: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/BirthdayQuest.jpg"
    });
```

if your system has a PATH variable set, this will be made accessible to you through process.env.PATH which you can use to check where binaries are located and make external calls to them if required. [source](https://codeburst.io/process-env-what-it-is-and-why-when-how-to-use-it-effectively-505d0b2831e7)

In your case there is no path, so try allocating via variable.